# Exclude directory in find

Tags: find

How can I find every file and directory matching a pattern, excluding one directory using `find`?

Say I have the following file structure;

```
.
  foo-exclude-me/
    foo.txt
  foo-exclude-me-not/
    foo.txt
  bar/
    foo.txt
    foobar/
      bar.txt
      foofoo.txt
```

how would I get the following output using `find`:

```
./bar/foo.txt
./bar/foobar
./bar/foobar/foofoo.txt
./foo-exclude-me-not
./foo-exclude-me-not/foo.txt
```

I have tried using both of the following command:

```
find . -name 'foo-exclude-me' -prune -o -name 'foo*'
find . -name 'foo*' \! -path './foo-exclude-me/*'
```

but both of them return this:

```
./bar/foo.txt
./bar/foobar
./bar/foobar/foofoo.txt
./foo-exclude-me # << this should be excluded
./foo-exclude-me-not
./foo-exclude-me-not/foo.txt
```

How can I properly exclude the `foo-exclude-me` directory?

Comment: Try using `foo-exclude-me` instead of `./foo-exclude-me`. Also try appending `-print` at the end of the command.

Comment: @MaxMackie perfect :)

Comment: It fixed it? Which was the fix that worked for you? I can put it in an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @MaxMackie using both `-print` and `foo-exclude-me` instead of `./foo-exclude-me`.

Comment: Awesome, looks like Gilles beat me to it though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
find . -name 'foo-exclude-me' -prune -o -name 'foo*' -print
```

With no `-print`, the implicit default action applies to every match, even pruned ones. The explicit `-print` applies only under the specified conditions, which are `-name 'foo*'` only in the else branch of `-name 'foo-exclude-me'`.

Generally speaking, use an explicit `-print` whenever you're doing something more complex than a conjunction of predicates.

Your second attempt with `! -path './foo-exclude-me/*'` didn't work because `./foo-exclude-me` doesn't match `./foo-exclude-me/*` (no trailing `/`). Adding `! -path ./foo-exclude-me` would work.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> -bash-4.1$ find . -exec ls -l {} + -name 'a.out' -prune -o -name '*' -exec rm -f {} + -exec ls -l {} +
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba  499 Jan 18 19:30 ./a.out
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba  499 Jan 18 20:59 ./b.out
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba  499 Jan 18 20:59 ./c.out
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba  499 Jan 18 20:59 ./d.out
>
> .:
> total 16
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba 499 Jan 18 19:30 a.out
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba 499 Jan 18 20:59 b.out
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba 499 Jan 18 20:59 c.out
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba 499 Jan 18 20:59 d.out
> rm: cannot remove `.': Is a directory
> ls: cannot access ./b.out: No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access ./d.out: No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access ./c.out: No such file or directory
> .:
> total 4
> -rw-r--r--. 1 oradba dba 499 Jan 18 19:30 a.out
> ```

Comment: Used the prune option to skip a.out and works fine - art.s

Comment: You absolutely do not explain why `-prune` is relevant.  `-prune` is one of the most convoluted options to `find` 'cause it disables `-print` (which is enabled by default)

Comment: -prune True;  if  the  file  is  a directory, do not descend into it. - So it will not work itself into the directories as a protection. - art.s