# Excluding a folder from deleting empty files with find

Tags: find

I usually delete empty files and folders in my home directory with find using the following command:

```
find /home/tjuh -empty -delete
```

However I would like to exlcude one folder, namely `/home/tjuh/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/` so I tried:

```
find . -not -path '/home/tjuh/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/' -empty
```

to see if that specific folder is excluded from the search but it's not really working the way I want it to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67217/exclude-directory-in-find?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

The `-path` argument is a pattern, so you have to use wildcards, or it will only match exact:

```
find . -not -path "./.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/*" -empty
```

Also, you have to use absolute or relative paths, not mix them. The above one is with relative paths, this one is with absolute paths:

```
find /home/tjuh -not -path "/home/tjuh/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/*" -empty
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude that directory *and all its descendents*, then `-prune` is what you need:

```
find "$HOME" -path "$HOME/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common" -prune -o -empty -delete
```

This means: if the path matches `$HOME/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common` then `-prune` (ignore it and its children) and continue, OR if `-empty` then `-delete` (and continue).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rm `find /home/tjuh -empty | grep -v "^/home/tjuh/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/"`
```