# How to list only directories that are not on a `.git` directory subpath?

Tags: find

I want to list only the directories that are not inside a .git/ directory on my current path.

I'm trying this:

```
find . -path "**/.git" -prune -o -print -type d
```

The .git dirs are excluded, but the snippet is also listing files. But it should not as I specified `-type d`. How to make the `find` utility behave as I described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used `-print` before `-type d`, so `find` print all things not satisfied the first expression.

You want to swap them:

```
find . -path '*/.git' -prune -o -type d -print
```

or using predicate only, so you can omit `-print`:

```
find . ! \( -path '*/.git' -o -path '*/.git/*' \) -type d
```

Also note that you only need to use one asterisk `*/.git`, double asterisk `**` has no special meaning to `find` pattern matching. And you can make it simpler, more portable and slightly faster by using `-name` instead of `-path`:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type d -print
```

Comment: thank you. The first solution worked. However, if I ommit -print, as you suggested, I get .git directories, which I don't want. If i put back the magical `-print`, than it all works as I want. Why that happens? That's really unexpected.

Comment: think I've found the answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67219/155613). Without `-print` the default action applies to all branches, even pruned ones.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I am not near my laptop to check. Here omit `-print` make it to be applied for the whole expression.

Comment: Thanks, now both solutions work fine. With prune I only have to specify `*/.git` while `find` needs us to say both `*/.git` and `*/.git/*` when using predicate only. Why is that?

Comment: Because `*/.git` can not match something like `foo/.git/bar`.

Comment: Ok, but why `*/.git` matches something like `foo/.git/bar` in the first case with `-prune`?

Comment: No, It's not pattern matching, `-prune` prevent `find` from looking into `.git` directory, any directories inside were ignored.

Comment: The version without `-prune` has the downside that `find` will recurse into `.git` directories and try every file there. This could be a performance hit.

Comment: Thank you @Gilles. So `-name .git -prune` is essentially the same thing as `-path '*.git' -prune`, but `-path` has better performance. Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

Due to lack of knowledge of the `find` command, I just use a less efficient but most likely equally useful and probably more readable one-liner that also involves `grep`:

```
find . -type d | grep -v "/\.git"
```

Comment: It's not equal. It gives wrong result if filename contain newline.

Comment: You'd need `grep -Ev '\.git($|/)'`, otherwise you're ignoring e.g. `.gitignore` files. And even then that would break on file names containing newlines (this one isn't always a concern in practice). Given that there's a simple `find` solution, such an alternate method is not called for.